# Where to put script tags in next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Pretty new to next.js, but so far loving the framework. I really like using materialize as my css framework, and normally I just throw their style and script tags (https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html) in the public index.html file, which is obviously not present in next.js. Would I just put that code in the _app.js file like so:

```
import '../styles/globals.css';
import Head from 'next/head';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js" />
      </Head>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
    )
}

export default MyApp
```

Just wondering what the proper syntax for that type of stuff is.

Comment: take a look [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document)

Comment: Very cool! Thank you, I assume that's where I would put my google analytics tags as well? Also, is the getInitialProps function necessary to perform the server side rendering?

Comment: yup. put google analytics tag there. I havn't tried so, cant say on `getInitialProps`